# Custom Background not Appearing

Tags: custom-background, add-theme-support

I have a very simple theme to which I need to add `custom-background` support.

When I go into `appearance -> customize`, I am able to select a background image.

However, the background of the site never actually changes, and I can see that the output html contains

```
<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support custom-background">
```

But there are no `<style>` tags to be seen.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be going wrong?

### header.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tutorial theme</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body <?php body_class(''); ?>>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>
```

### functions.php

```
<?php
    $defaults = array(
        'default-image' => '',
        'default-preset' => 'default',
        'default-position-x' => 'left',
        'default-position-y' => 'top',
        'default-size' => 'auto',
        'default-repeat' => 'repeat',
        'default-attachment' => 'scroll',
        'default-color' => '',
        'wp-head-callback' => '_custom_background_cb',
        'admin-head-callback' => '',
        'admin-preview-callback' => '',
    );
    add_theme_support('custom-background', $defaults );
?>
```

I also tried simply adding `add_theme_support('custom-background');` but no luck.

I am using version **4.7.5**

Comment: Could you please provide the theme's name?

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz `tutorial_theme`

Comment: `no-customize-support` body class suggests that you have  javascript disabled in your browser. Enable it.

Comment: Also, I cannot see a `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the `header.php` file. Even if its just a simple theme you maybe need this as plugins for example rely on this.

Comment: remove the '' from your function.